# AWS Glue - AWSGlueETL dependency not resolved

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aws-glue

I am trying to run Glue in my local using scala, so I added the below dependency as per the AWS Glue documentation(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>AWSGlueETL</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <!-- A "provided" dependency, this will be ignored when you package your application -->
</dependency>
```

But this dependency is not found(not resolving)

Please let me know if this dependency moved to some other name.

Thank you

AWSGlueETL should be resolving in pom.xml

Comment: *3.0.0 - for AWS Glue version 3.0*, *1.0.0 - for AWS Glue version 1.0 or 2.0*, *0.9.0 - for AWS Glue version 0.9*. **Not 2.0**

Answer (score 1):

I found that https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/ has only 3.0.0, 0.9.0 and 1.0.0 deps. There is no 2.0.0 published version. I found this issue related to this. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/issues/15